# Expo build error is not descriptive - Failed building JavaScript bundle

Tags: react-native, eslint, expo

I often get this error when changing things in my react-native project.

```
17:27:35: Failed building JavaScript bundle
17:27:42: Warning: 'react' peer dependency missing. Run `npm ls` in /Users/navalsaini/hf/nativeapp to see full warning.
17:27:42: 
17:27:42: If there is an issue running your project, please run `npm install` in /Users/navalsaini/hf/nativeapp and restart.
Building JavaScript bundle [========================================================================================= ] 99
```

Additionally when I run an eslint, I dont get any issues. (The ones blow are not entirely related to my code and I get them anyway - even when the project works)

```
/Users/navalsaini/hf/nativeapp/src/platforms/native/utils/fbAuth.js
  7:33  error  'Expo' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 1 problems (1 errors, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ReactNativeSeed@1.1.0 lint: `eslint . --fix`
```

Is there a better way to configure my expo build system?

My eslintrc looks as below.

```
cat .eslintrc.json 
{
  "extends": "expo/native",
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-no-bind": [false]
  }
}
```

This is important because it is a huge waste of my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have realised that if I want to know the exact build error, this is what works for me.

1. Push the currently modified code in repo to `stash` and go to last working commit
2. The application runs (as we are on a working commit)
3. Apply the stash - this triggers a rebuild while expo is running (and does not crash expo)

The `build` errors are dumped on simulator screen with a red background.

This does save me time as compared to tracing which change made the build break.

Comment: your approach was genius and saved me a ton of time!